# View is not loaded when custom viewController added as a root view controller instead of Navigation Controller as the self.window.rootViewController

Tags: ios

I am using the master-detail template of xcode 4.5.2. Instead of keeping `UINavigationController` as the `rootViewController` of the `UIWindow`, I am replacing it with my own ViewController with a simple splash screen as its view. After the splash screen is displayed I want to push the `navigationController` as the `self.window.rootviewController` (which contains master and `detailViewControllers`).

The issue is although my `ViewController` is getting initialised and its `viewDidLoad` is getting called but its view (splash screen is not getting displayed).

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions

{self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];

if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)

{LoginViewController *loginViewController = [[[LoginViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LoginViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil] autorelease];
//        loginViewController.masterViewController = loginViewController;

          [self.window setRootViewController:loginViewController];
          [self.window addSubview:loginViewController.view];

if (BOOL condition is YES)
{
 MasterViewController *masterViewController = [[[MasterViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MasterViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil] autorelease];
        self.navigationController = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:masterViewController] autorelease];
        //self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;
}
```

The `LoginViewController` is the custom controller with the splash screen. So how to change the launch screen from App delegate when using a navigation controller? (Master-Detail Template)

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not the way to do this. You should leave the master-detail structure as is (as the root view controller of the window), and present your splash screen as a modal view controller when the app first launches. Just present your LoginViewController with presentViewController:animated: in the viewDidLoad method of the master view controller.

After Edit: if you want to do it the way that you're trying, the code you have is almost right. It can be done from the login controller (rather than the app delegate) with the following code:

```
if (BOOL condition is YES) {
     MasterViewController *masterViewController = [[[MasterViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MasterViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil] autorelease];
     UINavigationController *navigationController = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:masterViewController] autorelease];
     self.view.window.rootViewController = navigationController;
}
```

Comment: Well i understand your point but as it says LoginViewController ,without proper authentication i can't allow control to pass to the masterViewController which is the entry point of the navigation controller. So I have to keep the LoginViewController seperate from the navigation stack.

Comment: @user1671848, that doesn't mean you can't do it the way I suggested. You just have code in your login controller, such that if login fails, it shows some content explaining that the login failed, and that screen just stays there until the user closes the app.

Comment: @user1671848, I've updated my answer to show you how to do it, if you want to use the structure you're proposing.

Comment: I tried implementing your code in the loginViewController but the app crashes saying in the console: -[LoginViewController :]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x756ed40

Comment: @user1671848. there's nothing in the code I posted being sent to the LoginViewController (other than view, which shouldn't cause a problem), so I'm not sure why you get that error. It would be best if you updated your post to show the whole method, where you're doing this.

Comment: yes the view had the prblem. I am not using  ARC so hv to uncheck the uncheck the autolayout of the xib files,.